# Looping through nested class object

Tags: c#

I have generated these classes from a JSON feed (SendGrid API category stats):

```
public class Metrics
{
    public int blocks { get; set; }
    public int bounce_drops { get; set; }
    public int bounces { get; set; }
    public int clicks { get; set; }
    public int deferred { get; set; }
    public int delivered { get; set; }
    public int invalid_emails { get; set; }
    public int opens { get; set; }
    public int processed { get; set; }
    public int requests { get; set; }
    public int spam_report_drops { get; set; }
    public int spam_reports { get; set; }
    public int unique_clicks { get; set; }
    public int unique_opens { get; set; }
    public int unsubscribe_drops { get; set; }
    public int unsubscribes { get; set; }
}

public class Stat
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Metrics metrics { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string date { get; set; }
    public List<Stat> stats { get; set; }
}
```

And populate as follows:

```
RootObject Datalist = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString);
```

I want to loop through the data in order to display it and save to a database. I can loop through RootObject as follows:

```
Type type = Datalist.GetType();
PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();

foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
{
    Response.Write("Name: " + property.Name + ", Value: " + property.GetValue(Datalist, null) + "<br>");
}
```

But how do I loop through:

- RootObject

  - Stat

    - Metrics

?

Comment: How about `RootObject.Stat[i].Metric` Or in your example it would become `Datalist.stats[i].metrics.blocks`

Comment: Do you just want all the `Metrics` instances in the `RootObject`? You can use `SelectMany` for that, e.g. `RootObject.SelectMany(ro => ro.Stats).SelectMany(stats => stats.Metrics)`.